# How do I plot a histogram using Python so that x-values are frequencies of a spectra?

Tags: python, matplotlib, fft, histogram

I looked at the python "matplotlib.pylab" library, and allows me to plot histograms with the "plt.hist" function.  The problem is that it only takes one data argument, which is an array.  In my case, I want to plot a histogram of the data produced by a fourier transform.  A fourier transform shows the relative quantity of various frequencies.  So I could put this array of quantities into "plt.hist" and get an informative chart, but the x-axis would not be in the units of frequencies.  My guess is that the x-axis would just be the indices of the array, but even that doesn't seem to be correct when I plot it.
Thanks,

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding of what a 'histogram' is. `plt.plot` takes two arguments (for x and y axes). You can use this to plot a spectrum (or whatever fft-like output you want) vs frequency. You may also want to take a look at `plt.bar`.

Comment: @GideonIsaac A Fourier Transform or a DFT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naive answer for making a *histogram* of  `X`, the DFT of a time domain signal `x`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

...
w = np.linspace(0,N*dw-dw,N)   
plt.bar(w, abs(X), align='center', width=dw)
plt.show()
```

For a nice looking plot, you have to take into account that `X` is associated with frequencies `0*dw, 1*dw, ..., (N-1)*dw` and that, in a nice looking plot, you usually want to use a range `-N*dw/2`, `+N*dw/2` for your abscissas.

#### Complete answer

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(57)

N = 64 ; dw = 0.2
w = np.linspace(0,N*dw-dw,N)
X = 200 + (np.arange(N)-N/2)**2*np.random.random(N)

plt.bar(w, abs(X), align='center', width=dw)
plt.xticks([i*8*dw for i in range(N/8)]+[N*dw-dw/2])
plt.xlim(-dw/2,N*dw-dw/2)
plt.show()
```

And this is the result so far

[image]

as you can see, this type of plot kind of stresses the periodicity of the DFT, but it is customary to plot the DFT centered around the zero frequency, and this can be done like this

```
w2=np.concatenate((w-N*dw,w))
X2=np.concatenate((X,X)

plt.bar(w2, abs(X2), align='center', width=dw)
plt.xticks([i*8*dw for i in range(-N/16,1+N/16)])
plt.xlim(-dw*N/2,dw*N/2)
plt.show()
```

and this is the result
[image]

#### Post Scriptum

The procedures I described are good procedures for the OP needs, but I'd like to say that the `X` data has thoughtlessly been synthesized on the spot, and has no resemblance with real life DFT. On the contrary, if I see something like the plots above I'd make a comment on the insufficient sampling rate in time domain.